# ruby 2.0, why is #each_line mutating File object

Tags: ruby, file, printing, each, mutated

I'm running irb as a one-off text preprocessing tool.  I ran into immediate trouble just printing the text.

```
foo = File.open "bar"
foo.each_line {|l| puts l}
```

This prints as intended and returns `#<File:emails plaintext>`.

However, if I call `#each_line` again on the same object, no printing occurs, though it still returns `#<File:emails plaintext>`.

Why are the contents of the `File` object being overwritten by a call to `#each_line`?  I thought the raison d'etre of `#each`-like methods was to ensure mutation does not occur.  What is the proper 'ruby way' to do this?

Comment: `each` methods have nothing to do with the mutation. These concepts are orthogonal.

Comment: However, I have only entered 3 lines into irb, and this has occurred, hence my confusion.  My reasoning was that unless you specifically command a mutation to occur within the scope of a block passed to each, no changes will occur, nor should `#puts`-like methods alter state.

Comment: File is an I/O object. It has a concept of current position. You read the file to the end. There's no more content to return.

Comment: Oh okay I didn't know enough about file streams

Comment: If you open a file this way, don't forget to close it ( `foo.close` ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to [rewind it](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-rewind): `foo.rewind`.

Consider how `$stdin.each_line` ought to behave. Since an IO object could be a file on disk, or it could be a stream or a pipe, it doesn’t make sense to guarantee that you can randomly seek around in it. Load it into an array if you want to iterate multiple times.

Comment: I appreciate the additional presentation of different options for accomplishing what I need as well as the technical explanation